# C#: capture windowstate changes of another application (wrote in c/c++ i think)

Tags: c#, winforms, capture, windowstate, cross-application

I have a situation where I need to capture windowstate changes of another window (which is not owned by my application and I didn't wrote it. I think it's written in C++).

Actually I'm using a separate thread where I constantly do GetWindowState and fire custom events when this value changes (I have the handle of the window), but I would like to know if there is a better method

Thanks,

P.S.
I'm using winform if can be useful in any way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//use this in a timer or hook the window
//this would be the easier way
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class WindowState
{
    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern int IsWindowEnabled(int hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern int IsWindowVisible(int hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern int IsZoomed(int hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern int IsIconic(int hWnd);

    public static bool IsMaximized(int hWnd) 
    {
        if (IsZoomed(hWnd) == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public static bool IsMinimized(int hWnd)
    {
        if (IsIconic(hWnd) == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public static bool IsEnabled(int hWnd)
    {
        if (IsWindowEnabled(hWnd) == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public static bool IsVisible(int hWnd)
    {
        if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd) == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: of course this assumes you know how to obtain the window's handle. if you don't just read a tutorial on the Win32 API. particularly, the FindWindow and FindWindowEx functions. An API spy would be useful as well. check our patorjk.com, they have a good API spy for free.

Comment: I don't see the point here, I asked how to **capture** windowstate changes, not how to check it which is far easier

Comment: If you use this class in a timer, saving the window state everytime the timer executes then you will know when the window state has changed. It's very simple. If you are trying to prevent a window's state very being changed thats something different, and something you would need to be more clear about. I could provide code to do that as well

Comment: I'm doing it in this way at the moment, maybe this is the best solution if you don't wanna do **a lot** of work

Answer (score 1):

You can hook WNDPROC and intercept messages with that. You can either inject a DLL into the target process, open the process with debug priveleges or set a global hook to WH_CALLWNDPROC.

Comment: Neither of which you can do with C#.

Comment: Well it's not a problem if I have to write something with C++, the problem, however I think is too complex for such a tool I'm trying to develop...

Comment: @Hans , you can use interop (p/invokes) to achieve such a thing with C#.